# Missing $template parameter in prestashop 1.7.6, when rendered from hook

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm using Prestashop 1.7.6.4. I want to render a template in a hook. I'm doing that via the following code:

```
class MyModuleName extends PaymentModule
{

    public function hookActionValidateOrder($params)
    {
        /**
         * Verify if this module is enabled
         */
        if (!$this->active) {
            return;
        }

        if (Configuration::get('inline')) {
            $this->context->smarty->assign([
                'module' => $order->module
            ]);

            return $this->display(__FILE__,
                'views/templates/hook/displayStatusOrder.tpl');

        }
        // more code goes here
    }

}
```

Do note that I've also tried with

```
return $this->fetch('module:myModule/views/templates/hook/displayStatusOrder.tpl');
```

results are the same.

However I'm getting the following error:

```
(1/1) SmartyException
0():Missing '$template' parameter
```

I'm absolutely sure that my template exists. And it has the correct name.

My folder structure is like so:

```
myModuleName
  views
    templates
      hook
        displayStatusOrder.tpl
```

I've tried deleting the cache, reinstalling the module, etc etc.

I'm clearly missing something obvious.

Comment: `hookActionValidateOrder` is an action hook, not a display hook, you can not display a template.

Comment: Yeah, I figured I was doing something wrong. So what are my options here?

Comment: Where do you want to display this template?

Comment: No surprise, you were right. I can't display templates in an action hook. I ended up rerouting to a controller. I had to display some custom javascript for a payment method. Either way, if you post your first comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hookActionValidateOrder` is an action hook, not a display hook, so you can not display a template.

You need to check in your template where you want to display your code which hooks are available.